llm.with_structured_output() NotImplementedError
I follow the oficial langchain tutorial https://python.langchain.com/docs/how_to/structured_output/ to enable structured output on gpt-4o and get the following error:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/engineer/workspace/ScansOrganizer/./llm-scan.py", line 66, in main
    model_with_structured_output = llm.with_structured_output(ScannedDocumentMetadata)
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/engineer/workspace/ScansOrganizer/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/chat_models.py", line 1238, in with_structured_output
    llm = self.bind_tools([schema], tool_choice="any")
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/engineer/workspace/ScansOrganizer/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/chat_models.py", line 1115, in bind_tools
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError

Pckage
pipenv run pip show langchain
Loading .env environment variables...
Name: langchain
Version: 0.3.13
Summary: Building applications with LLMs through composability
Home-page: https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain
Author: 
Author-email: 
License: MIT
Location: /Users/engineer/workspace/ScansOrganizer/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages
Requires: aiohttp, langchain-core, langchain-text-splitters, langsmith, numpy, pydantic, PyYAML, requests, SQLAlchemy, tenacity
Required-by: langchain-community

Python 3.12
Schema
class ScannedDocumentMetadata(BaseModel):
    """Classified scanned document"""
    file_name: str = Field(description="A document file name without extension. Includes the date if preseneted in the document text, type of document, short summary of document and place.")
    type: str = Field(description="type of the document: contract, application, receipt, mail, bill")

And code snippet
llm = ChatOpenAI(
        temperature=0,
        openai_api_key=os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY"),
        model_name="gpt-4o"
    )
model_with_structured_output = llm.with_structured_output(ScannedDocumentMetadata)
classification_result = model_with_structured_output.invoke(f"Classify the following scanned document text\n<text>{text_extracted}</text>")
print(classification_result)

What could be the reason? I see that gpt-4o supports the structured_output.
